# Why is the number of conjugacy classes modulo 16 equal to the order for a finite group of odd order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, congruences

Let $G$ be a group of odd order $n$ and suppose $|Con(G)| = k$  ( Con(G) is the set of conjugacy classes of G), prove that $$k \equiv n \pmod{ 16}.$$ How do I proceed on this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathrm{Con}(G)$?

Comment: The set of conjugacy classes of $G$, I guess.

Comment: Assuming Andreas' guess is correct, you can find a proof under https://drexel28.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/representation-theory-the-number-of-conjugacy-classes-of-a-finite-group-of-odd-order-is-equivalent-to-the-order-of-the-group-modulo-sixten/